# Encrpyt/Decrpyt program using functions c++

Tags: c++, xor

Hello total amateur here, been learning c++ for the last two months. I'm not so acute with my understanding of functions, and even less so with some of the operators in c++ (like xor). I'm writing a program that will take a string from the user, encrypt it using the ^ operator and then decrypt it. I think I have the basic foundation down, but im getting some weird outputs and I think it has something to do with my for loop, or perhaps my use of XOR. my program below, any help would be great appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const short SIZE = 132;
class deer
{

public:
char inputdata();
char encryptdata(char inputbuffer[SIZE], char encryptbuffer[SIZE]);
char inputbuffer[SIZE];
char encryptbuffer[SIZE];
char decryptbuffer[SIZE];
char decrpytdata(char n[], char p[]);
long e;
long count;


};

int main()
{
deer obj;
obj.inputdata();
obj.encryptdata(obj.inputbuffer, obj.encryptbuffer);
obj.decrpytdata(obj.encryptbuffer, obj.decryptbuffer);

system("pause");
return 0;
}

char deer::inputdata()
{
cout << "please enter your text to be encrpyted" << endl;
cin.getline(inputbuffer, SIZE);
cin.gcount();
count =cin.gcount();
count--;
cout << inputbuffer << endl;
return 0;


}

char deer::encryptdata(char inputbuffer[], char encryptbuffer[])
{
short key = 0xAC;
int i = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {

    inputbuffer[i] = encryptbuffer[i] ^= key;
    cout << encryptbuffer << endl;

}
return *encryptbuffer;


}

char deer::decrpytdata(char encryptbuffer[], char decryptbuffer[])
{
int i = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {

    encryptbuffer[i] ^= decryptbuffer[i];

}
cout << decryptbuffer << endl;

return decryptbuffer;
}
```

Comment: Towards the bottom, shouldn't the line be `decryptbuffer[i] ^= encryptbuffer[i];`? In C and C++, the convention is to make the first argument the result, and to prevent these kinds of errors you should declare the input array as `const`, ie `char const encryptbuffer[]`.

Comment: Okay, I will fix my formatting on that. I've failed to mention that I'm not allowed to use any globals or constants for this program, save the first SIZE const. thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

The encryption and decryption using XOR needs the same key (says 0xAC in the code). The `encryptbuffer` is generated by XOR-ing the `inputbuffer` with the key and the `decryptbuffer` is generated by XOR-ing the `encryptbuffer` with the key. Therefore, the key need to be the member of the `deer`.

Since `inputbuffer`, `encryptbuffer`, and `decryptbuffer` are members of the class deer, it's not need to put them as parameters when calling the member functions `enctyptdata` and `decryptdata`.

The encryption function:

```
char deer::encryptdata()
{
    for (int i=0; i&lt;count; ++i)
    {
        encryptbuffer[i] = inputbuffer[i] ^ key;
    }
    cout &lt;&lt; encryptbuffer &lt;&lt; endl;
}
```

The decryption function:

```
char deer::decryptdata()
{
    for (int i=0; i&lt;count; ++i)
    {
        decryptbuffer[i] = encryptbuffer[i] ^ key;
    }
    cout &lt;&lt; decryptbuffer &lt;&lt; endl;
}
```

The deer class:

```
class deer
{
    static const char key = 0xAC;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Hey Dude! this was great help, I'm still getting some crazy outputs, For instance when I enter my string in, lets say "Hello have a nice day", it drowns my screen with a bunch of weird icons. not sure this is intended, as I thought it would only encrypt the number of bits it reads from the string. In any case thank you very much for taking your time to help, this is defintely pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: The display of weird icons in `encryptbuffer` is reasonable since the value of XOR-ed character may not be alphanumeric. The way to verify the encryption/decryption is to check the output of `encryptdata`. If the value of `decryptbuffer` is equivalent to `inputbuffer` then the methods are okay.